# How to depend on a sub-project of multimodule SBT project from Github

Tags: scala, sbt

I can add a dependency on the `commons` root like this:

```
lazy val commons = RootProject(uri("ssh://git@github.com:foo/commons.git"))
lazy val thisProject = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(commons)
```

But what if I want to depend on a specific `commons` sub-project (the `commons` repository contains a multi-module SBT project). E.g. (in pseudo-code):

```
lazy val commonDbStuff = RootProject(uri("ssh://git@github.com:foo/commons.git")).sub("commons-db") // pseudo-code
lazy val thisProject = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(commonsDbStuff)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lazy val commonDbStuff = 
  ProjectRef(uri("ssh://git@github.com/foo/commons.git"), "commons-db")
```

Comment: I edited the answer because in `0.13.13` there should be `/` after domain instead of `:` ... I don't know if it was like this all the time or it changed in one of previous sbt versions ...